# Slow $group in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I am working to fetch data from mongodb using $group. I have modified my query to

```
db.mydata.aggregate([{ $match: {"CreatedOn": {$lte: ISODate("2015-10-27T03:45:09Z"),
"$gte":  ISODate("2015-09-09T07:37:27.526Z")}} },
{"$group" : { "_id" : "$myIP" , "total" : { "$sum" : "$SuccessCount"}}}, 
{ "$project" : { "myIP" : "$_id" , "_id" : 0 , "Total" : "$total"}}, 
{ "$sort" : { "Total" : -1}}, { "$limit" : 10}])
```

But it is taking more than 2 minute to execute, even for small amount of data. I have created index for CreatedOn. I have also created index for myIP.

I have document structure like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55d33d7045cedc287ed840a3"),
"myIP" : "10.10.10.1","SuccessCount" : 1,
"CreatedOn":ISODate("2015-10-27T03:45:09Z")
 }
```

I want success count's by all  myIP's with maximum on top.

Comment: Putting the sort stage in front of the group stage should improve the situation.

Comment: I already put small date range, this is only 10 million records. Do we have some other work around, instead of using group? Since I tested only group is creating issue.

Comment: Check your index coverage: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/ and this is a starter on results: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/

Comment: @sangita Order matters. So please set up the pipeline up like this: `$match->$sort->$group`

Comment: @ Markus W Mahlberg: When I do $match->$sort->$group, it takes around 7 minutes but for $match->$group->$sort it took 2.5 minute. Since 2.5 minute is big time to load data on UI, my job is to reduce it. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I have edited my question. Please have a look into it.

Comment: @sangita Ok, which of the "put the sort stage ***in front of the group stage***" don't you get, hm? ;)

Comment: No. Its taking more time that way. I have put my new query. Can I reduce it in another form to take less time?